# Prove that the decomposition of a linear operator into a sum of a self-adjoint and anti-self-adjoint operator is unique

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Prove that the decomposition of a linear operator into a sum of a self-adjoint and anti-self-adjoint operator is unique

My ideas: is to use fact that set of self-adjoint operators generate vector space.

Comment: Hint: if $A + B = C + D$, then $A^\dagger + B^\dagger  = C^\dagger  + D^\dagger $.

Answer (score 1):

If $S_1+A_1=S_2+A_2$, with $S_1,S_2$ selfadjoint and $A_1,A_2$ anti-selfadjoint, then the operator
$$
T=S_1-S_2=A_2-A_1
$$
is both selfadjoint and anti-selfadjoint. That is, $T^*=-T^*$, so $T^*=0$.